# free function for a Cstring in Julia

Tags: julia, c-strings

I have a function in Julia that creates a proper `Cstring`. This `Cstring` is put into memory that is allocated by `malloc`, hence after usage, the memory needs to be freed. I want a function in Julia that accepts a `Cstring` or a pointer/reference to it, frees the memory using a call to C's `free` and the equivalent of the `char*` needs to be set to NULL. A function that 'just' frees and that takes a `Cstring` is easily written. The problem is in setting the `Cstring` pointer to NULL. In C, such a function would accept an argument like `char** mem_p_p` and execute `free(*mem_p_p); *mem_p_p = NULL`. In Julia, I fail to see how to reference a `Cstring` to obtain the `char**` equivalent. I have read the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#C-Interface%20but%20fail) to connect the dots. Please help.

### Edit 1:

My failing attempt:

```
    function free_cstring_null!(c_string_p::Ptr{Cstring})::Nothing
        println("free_cstring_null!(): Started.")
        println("free_cstring_null!(): c_string_p ", c_string_p)

        c_string = unsafe_load(c_string_p)
        println("free_cstring_null!(): c_string ", c_string)

        @ccall printf("free_cstring_null!(): Calling from C: %s\n"::Ptr{UInt8}, c_string::Cstring)::Cint;

        Base.unsafe_store!(c_string_p, C_NULL)
        # *c_string_p = NULL

        return nothing
    end
```

### Edit 2:

I have tried to make things simpler by just doing memory management on a single Float64. I can not get that working either because Julia seems not to support taking a pointer here either. The analogue goal of this Float64 study is to create a ccallable Julia function that frees the memory and sets the pointer from malloc back to NULL, which mitigates the risks of double free.

```
Base.@ccallable function free_and_null_float!(mem_p_p::Ptr{Ptr{Float64}})::Nothing
    println("free_and_null_float!(...): mem_p_p ", mem_p_p, " ### typeof(mem_p_p) ", typeof(mem_p_p))
    mem_p = unsafe_load(mem_p_p)
    println("free_and_null_float!(...): mem_p ", mem_p, " ### typeof(mem_p) ", typeof(mem_p))

    @ccall free(mem_p::Ptr{Cchar})::Cvoid

    mem_p = C_NULL

    return nothing
end

function double_memory()::Nothing

    myDouble::Float64 = 666.666
    # Create some dummy Float64

    mem_p::Ptr{Float64} = @ccall malloc(8::Int)::Ptr{Float64}
    # Allocate memory to dump the Float64 in.

    unsafe_store!(mem_p, myDouble)
    # Dump the Float64 in the memory

    myDoubleFromMalloc::Float64 = unsafe_load(mem_p)
    # Create a new Float64 and dereference mem_p

    println("myDoubleFromMalloc ", myDoubleFromMalloc)
    # Show the dereferenced Float64.

    arg = pointer(mem_p) # ... I can not get this to work either.
    free_and_null_float!(arg)
    return nothing
end
```

### Edit 3

Back to the string case.

```
        my_Cstring::Cstring = Cstring(mem_p)
        println("my_Cstring ", my_Cstring, " ### typeof(my_Cstring) ", typeof(my_Cstring))

        arg = Ptr{Cstring}(pointer(my_Cstring))
        # This does not throw an error, but it behaves like a cast. It does not
        # return the address of variable my_Cstring, it returns my_Cstring itself;
        # Cstring is just a pointer.

        println("arg ", arg, " ### typeof(arg) ", typeof(arg))

        free_and_null_string!(arg)
        println("After free_and_null(...), mem_p is ", mem_p)
        println("After free_and_null(...), arg   is ", arg)
        @ccall printf("Reading from the copy is dereferencing... '%s'\n"::Ptr{Cchar}, mem_p::Ptr{Cchar})::Cvoid
```

... and the counterpart free function is the core of the question:

```
Base.@ccallable function free_and_null_string!(mem_p_p::Ptr{Cstring})::Cvoid
    println("free_and_null!(...): mem_p_p ", mem_p_p, " ### typeof(mem_p_p) ", typeof(mem_p_p))

    mem_p::Ptr{Cchar} = unsafe_load(mem_p_p)
    println("free_and_null!(...): mem_p ", mem_p, " ### typeof(mem_p) ", typeof(mem_p))

    # @ccall free(mem_p::Ptr{Cchar})::Cvoid

    if false
        unsafe_store!(mem_p_p, C_NULL)
        # This is supposed to set the caller's argument, like in C, but since pointer
        # pointer(Cstring) returns Cstring, just just sets the first character of the
        # allocated memory to zero. Replace false with true and look at the output of
        # printf on the calling side.
    else
        unsafe_store!(mem_p_p + 10, C_NULL)
    end

    return nothing
end
```

Comment: Please show us your existing function.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want Julia to manage the validity of the pointer, while you want C to manage the memory pointed to by the pointer so that, when you call `free_cstring_null!(x)`, C frees the memory pointed to by `x` and Julia invalidates whatever `x` is.

Julia cannot reassign `Ptr` objects in the same way that C can reassign pointers, so trying to do something like `ptr = @ccall malloc(...); ptr = C_NULL` will only reassign the symbol `ptr`, not change what it points to. However, Julia does have a mechanism that works very similarly to C's pointers: [`Ref{T}`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Core.Ref). try using a `Ref{Cstring}` rather than a `Ptr{Cstring}`, assigning it with the `x = Ref(value)` method and dereferencing it with the `x[]` syntax, like so:

```
const str = "Hello, Julia!"

function allocate()
    ptr = @ccall malloc((length(str) + 1)::Csize_t)::Cstring # char *
    @ccall strcpy(ptr::Cstring, str::Cstring)::Cstring       # copy to memory
    @ccall printf("%s\n"::Cstring ; ptr::Cstring)::Cint      # prove it's really there
    return Ref(ptr)                                          # return a Ref{Cstring} for Julia to control
end

function free_cstring_null!(x::Ref{Cstring})
    if !isassigned(x)
        return                       # mimic `free(0)` for unassigned references
    end
    @ccall free(x[]::Cstring)::Cvoid # free the memory in C
    x[] = C_NULL                     # set the Ref's value to 0 to prevent double freeing memory
    return
end
```

A demonstration of what you will see when this is run:

```
julia> ref = allocate()
Hello, Julia!
Base.RefValue{Cstring}(Cstring(0x0000015e02b1e730))

julia> free_cstring_null!(ref)

julia> ref
Base.RefValue{Cstring}(Cstring(0x0000000000000000))

julia> free_cstring_null!(ref)  # safe to free again
```

Obviously you have to be careful with this sort of implementation because Julia doesn't actually own the memory behind the `Cstring` pointer. All it owns and knows how to garbage collect is the `Cstring` pointer itself: if you lose track of that pointer or forget to free the underlying memory before the `Ref{Cstring}` falls out of scope, your program will leak memory.

## A side note about the funny way Julia implements Cstring

I could have been using `Ptr{Cchar}` instead of `Cstring` for all the argument types I passed to `@ccall`, but I didn't want to type all those curly braces. In Julia, `Cstring` is only sort-of like `Ptr{Cchar}`: it's actually just another name for the same underlying primitive type. The definition of `Cstring` is strangely in [refpointer.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/0a696a3842750fcedca8832bc0aabe9096c7658f/base/refpointer.jl#LL79C5-L79C5):

```
if Int === Int64
    primitive type Cstring  64 end
    primitive type Cwstring 64 end
else
    primitive type Cstring  32 end
    primitive type Cwstring 32 end
end
```

This mirrors the definition of `Ptr{T}`, which is implemented in C, but [documented as](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Primitive-Types):

```
# 32-bit system:
primitive type Ptr{T} 32 end

# 64-bit system:
primitive type Ptr{T} 64 end
```

But because `Cstring <: Ptr == false`, the things that one ought to be able to do with `Cstring` because it is a pointer-like thing won't always work. The `pointer` method is like that, which, as you correctly identified, is defined in [c.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/0a696a3842750fcedca8832bc0aabe9096c7658f/base/c.jl#L186) to be a simple conversion to a `Ptr{Cchar}`:

```
pointer(p::Cstring) = convert(Ptr{Cchar}, p)
```

Unfortunately, because `Ptr{T}` is an immutable primitive type, Julia cannot create a pointer to the return value of `pointer(p::Cstring)`, so `pointer(pointer(p))` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. Indeed, I need Julia code to call malloc via the ccall macro. Also, I need the creation of the C-string to be ccallable. My analogue of your allocate() function now just returns a Cstring, but I need it to use a function argument. This is the same problem I have as in the free function. So, in short, I need both functions to be ccallable and using an argument rather than a return value. When I make the Ref-based free_cstring_null ccallable, Julia says: "argument types must be concrete".

Comment: @TradingDerivatives.eu Could using `RefValue{Cstring}` instead of `Ref{Cstring}` in the signature of `free_cstring_null` help? I would assume `Base.@ccallable` would still work as intended.

Comment: Base.@callable and Ref bite eachother. They can not be used together.

Comment: @PaSTE: Pointers in Julia are **mutable**, according to Julia's `ismutable` function.

Comment: What does `p = Ptr{Int8}(0); ismutable(p)` return?

Comment: @PaSTE: Apologies. `p = Ptr{Int8}(0); ismutable(p)` returns false. `ismutable(Ptr{Int8})` returns true. This is a pattern. `ismutable` returns true when offered the type name of an immutable struct and false when offered an object of that immutable struct. I don't understand why. I am on 1.9.0.